# VS2010 Database Project Linked Server Login Password

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, passwords, project, linked-server

This has been an ongoing saga trying to create a local database development environment using isolated development environment settings. I have two database projects, a server project that targeted a shared SQL Server 2005 instance and a database project that targets my database.

I have determined that deploying the server project locally is next to impossible due to all of the various logins not being recognized on my PC and so forth, however, I need the linked servers from the server project for my database project. To overcome the issues with deploying the server project, I turned off deployment on the server project and added these statements to the PreDeployment script of my database project.

```
IF DB_ID('CreditScores') is null
CREATE DATABASE CreditScores

EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'

EXECUTE sp_dropserver N'CREDIT_SCORES_CALENDAR', 'droplogins';
EXECUTE sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'CREDIT_SCORES_CALENDAR', @srvproduct = N'vm-2cbstest', @provider = N'SQLNCLI', @datasrc = N'vm-2cbstest';
EXECUTE sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'CREDIT_SCORES_CALENDAR', @useself = N'FALSE', @rmtuser = N'cdtscr';
```

The database deployment works to a point, but then I receive the error message below when it attempts to add a stored procedure that refers to the linked server. The problem I'm guessing is that the login that is stored in the server project for the linked server has a password that is not being set when it is being created depsite the fact that it looks like a password is filled in. My question is, how do I assign this password without actually knowing the password?

```
  Creating [dbo].[report_open_close]...
  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "CREDIT_SCORES_CALENDAR" returned message "Communication link failure".
C:\SourceCode2010\CreditScores\Development\CreditScores\TECO.Database.SQLServer2005.CreditScores\sql\debug\TECO.Database.SQLServer2005.CreditScores.sql(150,0): Error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 10054, Level 16, State 1, Line 0 TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

C:\SourceCode2010\CreditScores\Development\CreditScores\TECO.Database.SQLServer2005.CreditScores\sql\debug\TECO.Database.SQLServer2005.CreditScores.sql(150,0): Error SQL01268: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 0 Login failed for user 'cdtscr'.
  An error occurred while the batch was being executed.
  Done executing task "SqlDeployTask" -- FAILED.
 Done building target "DspDeploy" in project "TECO.Database.SQLServer2005.CreditScores.dbproj" -- FAILED.
 Done executing task "CallTarget" -- FAILED.
Done building target "DBDeploy" in project "TECO.Database.SQLServer2005.CreditScores.dbproj" -- FAILED.
Done building project "TECO.Database.SQLServer2005.CreditScores.dbproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```